# await doesnt work with stream for me in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem where i want to read some data from database and i want my function to wait for the data before proceeding executing the rest of my code.  i am using stream with await and async but doesnt look like it is working for me.

here is my code

```
void updateIncome() async {
     Stream<List<IncomeData>> _currentEntries;
     _currentEntries =  database.watchIncomeForUpdate(this.income);
    await _currentEntries.forEach((List<IncomeData> x) {
        x.forEach((element) {
          print('AWAIT');
        }
        );
      });
      print('FINISH');
  }
```

here is the procedure that call my database and get data

```
Stream<List<IncomeData>> watchIncomeForUpdate(IncomeData entry)  {
   return  (select(income)..where((t) =>t.id.isBiggerOrEqualValue(entry.id) & t.groupId.equals(entry.groupId))
     ..orderBy([(t) => OrderingTerm(expression: t.dateReceived)])).watch();
  }
```

when i run the function updateIncome(), it prints FINISH first which make me believe that the await/async is not working by waiting for the foreach to loop through all elements in the list.
i tried to move the await keyword in the function call

```
_currentEntries =  await database.watchIncomeForUpdate(this.income);
```

i get a warning message:  await applied to Stream<List> which i not a Future
can someone help me? what i am doing wrong?

i want to wait for database to get the data, loop and print AWAIT then when finish, it should proceed with rest of code and print FINISH.  the function that call the database return 8 rows. so when i loop using foreach, it should print AWAIT 8 times follow by FINISH.

how can i fix my code so that the function calls the database ,loop through the elements and wait until the loop finish before proceeding with the rest of the code outside of the loop?

Comment: await doesn't work in forEach

Comment: Why are you using `watch` instead of `get`?

Comment: hi Richard, I am using watch because I want the stream to look for changes in my database and get those changes. for example, lets say i read my database and display my data in widget. i  then make a change in the database, then watch should look for any changes.  if this is not how it works, can you explain the difference between both and when i can use watch and when to use get?  also, do you know the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replies.  i figured it out.
i changed function from this

```
Stream<List<IncomeData>> watchIncomeForUpdate(IncomeData entry)  {
   return  (select(income)..where((t) =>t.id.isBiggerOrEqualValue(entry.id) & t.groupId.equals(entry.groupId))
     ..orderBy([(t) => OrderingTerm(expression: t.dateReceived)])).watch();
  }
```

to this

```
 Future<List<IncomeData>>  watchIncomeForUpdate(IncomeData entry)  async {
   return  (select(income)..where((t) =>t.id.isBiggerOrEqualValue(entry.id) & t.groupId.equals(entry.groupId))
     ..orderBy([(t) => OrderingTerm(expression: t.dateReceived)])).get();
  }
```

then call the procedure as

```
      data = await database.watchIncomeForUpdate(this.income);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **watchIncomeForUpdate** is not a Future function, you can't wait for a non-future function.

```dart
void updateIncome() async {
    await for(var x in database.watchIncomeForUpdate(this.income)){
        x.forEach((element) {
          print('AWAIT');
        }
        );
      });
      print('FINISH');
  }
```

> Ref: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams